# uiimagepickercontrolleroriginalimage memory waring

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a collection view (UICollectionViewController subclass) where I placed a UIBarButtonItem named "Take a photo". When I tap the bar button item my camera opens & I take a photo. In my project after "Use Photo" from camera it will move to a crop view controller where I crop the image after selecting the image from my crop view the image gets placed here in my collection view the current controller. In crop view I have two buttons use and cancel.My problem is when I take oddly 2,3 or 4 I receive a memory warning in console then the app crashes with a alert "application terminated due to memory pressure". I've been using this code, when I use `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` there is no issue instead if I use `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` I come across memory issue.

My problem is to provide a good quality image and this `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` provides a good quality than `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage`.I have to get rid of this memory issue and so I used this line `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];`but I couldn't able clear the memory warning.

```
- (IBAction)TakeaPhoto:(id)sender {

[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:FALSE withAnimation:NO];
    gallery=0;
picker1 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   picker1.delegate = self;
    self.resizeableCropArea =YES;
    self.cropSize=CGSizeMake(296, 350);
       picker1.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
   [self presentViewController:picker1 animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *image =  [info objectForKey:
                                  UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

  image_cap = [self imageTemp:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(320, 370)];

   dataTemp = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.0);

    CropViewController *cropController = [[CropViewController alloc] init];

   cropController.sourceImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];


   Original_img = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(cropController.sourceImage,0.0);

   [original_image addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:Original_img]];

    NSLog(@"source image=%@",cropController.sourceImage);

    cropController.resizeableCropArea = self.resizeableCropArea;

    cropController.cropSize = self.cropSize;

    cropController.delegate = self;

    Cancel_Image= cropController.sourceImage;

     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    [self.navigationController
     pushViewController:cropController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should compress your JPEG images. For example if you need that your images have a size less than 70kb, you can use this code:

```
    float compressionRate = 0.90;    // Initial compression rate
    float maxCompressionRate = 0.10; // Max compression rate

    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(outputImage, compressionRate);
    // Our limit of size is MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE (70000) and compressionRate is 0.03f
    while ([data length] > MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE && compressionRate >= maxCompressionRate) {
        compressionRate -= 0.03;
        data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(outputImage, compressionRate);
    }
```

Note: you can edit MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE with you desired size in bytes.